# nodejs - CRUD with user authorization

Tags: node.js, express

I finished my CRUD blog using nodejs + express.js but the only thing I need is everytime I go to 'post/:id/edit' or 'post/new' the browser ask for an admin user to continue with that request. This is to prevent that any user can create post in my blog.

How can I achieve that? I couldn't find anything about this. And I don't really need a CRUD for users because I will be the only one creating/editing post.

Thanks

Comment: You can use [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/) library for user authentication/authorization in node.js application.

Answer (score 0):

- As mentioned in the comment above, use passport.js to create the authentication part.
- Once you do that, you will have to create a middleware to make sure the user have authorization do handle particular case. Since you are using Node.js and Express.js this part will be super easy.

Suppose user wants to create a post

> router.get('/post/create',**authenticate.ensureUser**, function (req,
>   res) {}

authenticate.ensureUser: is middleware. Which will look like this :

```
> ensureUser: function(req,res,next){
>        if(req.isAuthenticated()){
>             return next() ;
>         }else{
>             req.flash('danger','Please login.');
>             res.redirect('/login');
>         }
>     },
```

Comment: seems to complicated for what I want. I need something like in Ruby: def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |name, password|
      name == "usuarioadmin" && password == "ameliemlp"
     end
end

Comment: @EzequielRamiro I don't have experience with Ruby so I can't comment on that part. But you will need some form of authentication. User should be logged in somehow. Passport.js is very easy to use. Just check their documentation. After that, you can just check if that user is authorized or not .. that's it !